# Two Variable side by side bar plot ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

[Image of sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4FAd.png)

Trying to make a side by side bar plot but the bars seem to be behind each other but can not get them to be side by side:*see image*

[image]

```
afg <- read.table(header=TRUE,
text="FG  biomass stdev   Year
1   287.6   237.5   2015
1   254.2   220.6   2016
2   309.9   126.3   2015
2   307.6   139.5   2016
3   339.6   175.5   2015
3   349.3   160.6   2016")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(afg,aes(afg$FG,afg$biomass,fill=afg$Year)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity",position=position_dodge(0.9),color="black")

library(reshape2)
afg.long <- melt(afg$Year,id="year")
ggplot(afg.long,aes(afg$FG,afg$biomass,fill=afg$Year)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity",position = "dodge")
```

Comment: I have added a picture of how my data is set up

Comment: I guess if you click on the figure it pops up, sorry if I am not doing this correctly this is my first time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be treated as a categorical variable, your column `Year` needs to be converted to type `factor`. Also note that variable selection with `$` should never be used inside of the `aes()` function.

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(afg, aes(x=FG, y=biomass, fill=factor(Year))) +
     geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")

ggsave("dodged_barplot.png", plot=p, height=4, width=6, dpi=150)


# Note that 'Year' is type integer.

str(afg)
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ FG     : int  1 1 2 2 3 3
#  $ biomass: num  288 254 310 308 340 ...
#  $ stdev  : num  238 221 126 140 176 ...
#  $ Year   : int  2015 2016 2015 2016 2015 2016
```

[image]